# flexbox doesn't do the right thing for me

Tags: css, flexbox

i am playing around with display: flex, and i cannot get it to do what i want: distribute three columns evenly. sounds simple and easy? then please look at this code:

```
<div class='main'>
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="center">article article article article article article article article article article article article article article article article article</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

my CSS looks like this

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.center, .left, .right {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

FIDDLE is here: http://jsfiddle.net/n2PSg/2/

you can see, the center DIV is stretching almost to 90% of the available width. i would expect it to be exactly 33% of the available width.

try to change the text inside the center DIV: if i change this to one single word "article", everything works as expected.

what am i thinking wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flex properties of a flex-item are:

- flex-grow
- flex-shrink
- flex-basis

You should set the flex-basis for your elements if you want to assure equal space distribution, otherwise it will distribute the space as needed:

```
.main > div{
   flex: 1 1 30%; /* using the shorthand */
}
```

See [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2PSg/4/)

Comment: Thanks for this, it works better now.

BUT what I really want is a setting where in my example the center DIV fills up the space without squeezing the left and the right column. So is there a way that the center column fills the remaining space AFTER the widths for the right and left columns.

See the Fiddle now: How do one tell the right column to not squeeze?

http://jsfiddle.net/n2PSg/5/

Comment: @Martin set `flex-shrink` to `0` in that case.

Comment: Thanks! Finally, that was the missing piece. To set "flex-shrink". Now everthings seems to work as expected.

Comment: You're welcome! If your problem has been solved, you can close your question by marking the answer. So everybody knows, your issue is settled.